# MySQL receiving inout parameters from stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on ASP project connected to MySQL database. Now I am trying to call procedure with INOUT parameters which will inform me how many rows were deleted. Unfortunately I am receiving error message at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery():

> Additional information: OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine
>   gta_geoptima_data.courrier_envoye_delete_row is not a variable or NEW
>   pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

My procedure:

```
DROP procedure if exists `courrier_envoye_delete_row`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure `courrier_envoye_delete_row`(IN param_oid binary(16), INOUT  courriers_Count integer, INOUT  dossiers_Count integer) 
BEGIN
    -- DECLARE dossiers_Count, courriers_Count integer;

    DELETE FROM courrier_envoye WHERE oid = param_oid limit 1;
    set courriers_Count = (SELECT ROW_COUNT());
    set dossiers_Count = 1;
    select @courriers_Count, @dossiers_Count;
END$$
```

My code:

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_oid", row_oid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courriers_Count", MySqlDbType.Int32);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dossiers_Count", MySqlDbType.Int32);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
singleItem.courriers_Count = (Int32) cmd.Parameters["@courriers_Count"].Value;
singleItem.dossiers_Count = (Int32) cmd.Parameters["@dossiers_Count"].Value;
```

Comment: 1. Why use this procedure at all? A simple `DELETE` statement reports the number of affected rows to the client.  2. Why the `select` statement within the sproc?  Simply setting the values of your `INOUT` parameters will suffice.  3. Why mixing local and user variables?

Comment: 4. Without `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` is indeterminate.  5.  You don't need a subquery: `SET courriers_Count = ROW_COUNT()` would suffice.  6. Your `INOUT` parameters appear to be `OUT` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify [parameter direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
.......
cmd.Parameters
    .AddWithValue("@courriers_Count", MySqlDbType.Int32)
    .Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cmd.Parameters
    .AddWithValue("@dossiers_Count", MySqlDbType.Int32)
    .Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
.......
```